# Convert Custom URL scheme to QR code (IOS)

Tags: ios, qr-code, url-scheme

My question is what can I do to convert the custom URL scheme to a QR code that can open an app.

Let's say I have a custom URL (myScheme://). It works if I type it on my phone's browser.
But if I just convert it through some online qr code generator, the qr code reader is not going to open the url in browser and just return me a plain text.

Does it mean I need to build an own QR code reader to handle it?

Comment: if the url scheme open in the browser/webview or is an actual url on your web and redirect to your app scheme, then it will work, else its just plain text

Comment: do u mean i need to build an actual url to redirect the app scheme?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on QR Code Reader apps. In my situation I have a custom URL (`itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=xxx`) [QR Reader for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qr-reader-for-iphone/id368494609?mt=8) works. But some customers said: "I can't install the app. QR just opens Safari.". There are so many QR Reader apps and we don't know which one is used.

But you can use your own web-site something like [this](https://developers.tune.com/sdk/deep-linking-to-your-mobile-app-from-your-website/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Site Name</title>
    <style>@media screen and (max-device-width:480px){body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}}</style>

    <!-- implement javascript on web page that first first tries to open the deep link
        1. if user has app installed, then they would be redirected to open the app to specified screen
        2. if user doesn't have app installed, then their browser wouldn't recognize the URL scheme
        and app wouldn't open since it's not installed. In 1 second (1000 milliseconds) user is redirected
        to download app from app store.
     -->
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    <!-- Deep link URL for existing users with app already installed on their device -->
        window.location = 'yourapp://app.com/?screen=xxxxx';
    <!-- Download URL (MAT link) for new users to download the app -->
        setTimeout("window.location = 'http://hastrk.com/serve?action=click&publisher_id=1&site_id=2';", 1000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- button to Download App for new app users -->
    <form action="http://hastrk.com/serve?action=click&publisher_id=1&site_id=2" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="Download" />
    </form>

    <!-- button to Open App to specific screen for existing app users -->
    <form action="yourapp://app.com/?screen=xxxxx" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="Open App" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then you should generate QR with website url. It will open in Safari and will redirect your app. (I hope so.)

Comment: so i may need to use C# .net to create a webpage and then publish it, right?

Comment: Just create a html page and publish it.